# zabbix & configuration apache proxy header with headers

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, proxy, zabbix, proxypass

I wanted to implement checking a page that is available for the two data centers. However, web scenarios zabbixie 2.2.1 does not properly handle headers. I got the idea that it will use for the apache proxy, but I think I made some mistakes in the configuration. Below is the two files and vhosts hosts file

### First Datacenter

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName firstDC.test.be
    ServerAdmin admins@test.com

    Header set Host "test.be"
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / https://222.222.22.22/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://222.222.22.22/



    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/firstDC.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/firstDC.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

### Second Datacenter

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName secondDC.test.be
    ServerAdmin admins@test.com

    Header set Host "test.be"
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / https://333.333.33.33/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://333.333.33.33/



    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/secondDC.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/secondDC.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

### Host file

```
127.0.0.1          firstDC.test.be secondDC.test.be
192.168.178.151    TESTLINUX   TESTLINUX.domain.local firstDC.test.be secondDC.test.be
```

Please give me advice where is mistake ?

Regards
Mick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typical use case for Zabbix 2.4 - custom headers in web monitoring - 
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/web_monitoring

Do you have any serious reason to use Zabbix 2.2?

IMHO you should to add:

```
RequestHeader set Host "test.be"
```

Comment: Works !, thx for help. Regards Mick